# CGAL: Error in compiling code

Tags: qt, cgal, delaunay

I am trying to implement a Delaunay triangulation on a pointcloud which is defined in 3d space with cartesian co-ordinates.

I am using QT on Windows 7 (64 bit) and the CGAL library to do the same.

The library is correctly installed.

Everytime I try to compile my program, I get the following type of error.

```
error C2065:    'FLT_RADIX' : undeclared identifier
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2065: 'FLT_MANT_DIG' : undeclared identifier
error C2057: expected constant expression
```

these errors are repeated, and thus in total there are more than a hundred error messages due to which, the compiling stops.

My .pro file looks like this.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-01-11T14:53:46
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = dt_trial
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\include\\CGAL
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\boost_1_51
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\include\\CGAL
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\include

LIBS += -LC:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\lib -CGAL_Core-vc100-mt-gd-4.1.lib
LIBS += -LC:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\lib -CGAL_ImageIO-vc100-mt-gd-4.1.lib
LIBS += -LC:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\lib -CGAL_Qt4-vc100-mt-gd-4.1.lib
LIBS += -LC:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\lib -CGAL-vc100-mt-gd-4.1.lib

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

On the CGAL forums, I read that this has something to do with the configuration flags, and if I understand correctly, then in QT it means the contents of the .pro file.

also I have asked this same question, on the cgal forums [here](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-Issues-of-CGAL-td4656055.html#a4656479)

Can anyone hint me to what the problem is?

Best Regards

thedorkknight

Comment: Laurent already answered your question on the mailing list: INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\include\\CGAL should be INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\include and C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\include\\CGAL should be C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\include

Comment: @sloriot could you then perhaps make that an answer here as well? It's nice to have an answer in the mailing list, but that does not help SO all that much. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution has been provided on the [CGAL discussion forum](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-Issues-of-CGAL-td4656055.html) by Laurent Rineau. In case someone is not able to access the link, here is what is written

> Now I understand what happened. Your include path is wrong, and when
>   the compiler is asked to include , because of the wrong
>   include path it finds  in the directory
>   C:\libraries\CGAL_4_1\include\CGAL. You must remove the suffixes
>   \CGAL from your paths, because the prefix "CGAL/" is part of the name
>   of CGAL headers. Here are the right values:
>
> ```
> INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\include
> INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\build\\include
> INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\boost_1_51
> INCLUDEPATH += C:\\libraries\\CGAL_4_1\\auxiliary\\gmp\\include
> ```